# Get Minimum Value From Four Related Table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

there is a couple of question I have,

first, as I read some of the articles and I know I shall implement the SQL code with using **inner Join** in this question. 
I have below ***Tables*** :

**Hospital Table :**

```
    id  |  hospital_name | adress  | city_id
   -------------------------------------------
    1   | pars           |   55,6LA|   2
    2   | ghaem          |   12.9GI|   2
    3   | Mehr           |   632.Sp|   2
    4   | Erfan          |   21,6UJ|   3
    5   | Razavi         |   31.jjI|   3
    6   | Mohab          |   65.Spi|   1
```

**Cities Table:**

```
    id  |  cityname 
   --------------------
    1   | LosAngels
    2   | NewYork
    3   | Colifornia
```

**Treatments Table:**

```
    id  |  TreatmentName 
   ----------------------
    1   | nose surgery   
    2   | Orthopedic  
    3   | Knee joint replacement
```

**treatment_prices Table :**

```
    id  |  Treatments_id | Hospital_id  | Price
   ------------------------------------------
    1   |       1        |       1      |   700
    2   |       1        |       6      |   800
    3   |       1        |       4      |   900
    4   |       2        |       1      |   500
    5   |       2        |       2      |   700
    6   |       2        |       3      |   300
    7   |       3        |       1      |   600
    7   |       3        |       2      |   450
```

my **question** is how can I found the minimum treatment price each hospital by city code.

I need something like below Table View If **city ID** is *2* :

```
    price  |  hospital_name | treatment_name| 
   -------------------------------------------
    700    | pars           |   nose surgery   
    300    | Mehr           |   Orthopedic     
    450    | ghaem          |   Knee joint replacement
```

this is my **SQL** Code :

```
SELECT Min(treatment_prices.dollar) AS price, 
       hospitals.name_en            AS hname, 
       treatments.title_en          AS title 
FROM   treatment_prices 
       INNER JOIN hospitals 
               ON hospitals.id = treatment_prices.hospital_id 
       INNER JOIN treatments 
               ON treatments.id = treatment_prices.treatment_id 
WHERE  hospitals.city_id = 2 
GROUP  BY treatment_prices.treatment_id
```

*But It does not work Well. Like Below photo : 
[image: Result of my SQL code]

any help Will appreciated.*

Comment: You say it doenst work, what doesnt work?

Comment: It's not going to work because you aren't grouping by all of the fields. If you use `MIN()` on one field the rest need to either also have some form of aggregation or need to be grouped in the `Group By`.

Comment: @haag1 okay what SQL look like is ?

Comment: Looking at your query, you're looking at all of the hospitals in a city and which one offers the cheapest price for each procedure, correct?

Comment: @Shawn yes its correct

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.X or 8+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to find out which procedure is cheapest in which hospital in a city.

In MySQL 5.x, you'll have to use some inner sub-queries to find the cheapest procedure by hospital, and then join that back to your tables again to get the data you need.

See the Fiddle for the setup.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17eecc2/1)

**MySQL 5.x**:

First, you want to find the cheapest price for a procedure, filtering by your required City and the Hospitals in that city.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT tp.Treatments_ID, min(tp.Price) AS price
FROM treatment_prices tp
INNER JOIN Hospital h ON tp.Hospital_ID = h.ID
  INNER JOIN Cities c ON h.city_id = c.id
    AND c.ID = 2
GROUP BY tp.Treatments_ID
```

This gives you

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17eecc2/1/0)**:

```
| Treatments_ID | price |
|---------------|-------|
|             1 |   700 |
|             2 |   300 |
|             3 |   450 |
```

Now, you can use this as your sub-query to link back to your main tables again to retrieve the data you're looking for.

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT t2.TreatmentName, h2.Hospital_Name, s1.Price
FROM (
    SELECT tp.Treatments_ID, min(tp.Price) AS price
    FROM treatment_prices tp
    INNER JOIN Hospital h ON tp.Hospital_ID = h.ID
      INNER JOIN Cities c ON h.city_id = c.id
        AND c.ID = 2
    GROUP BY tp.Treatments_ID 
) s1
INNER JOIN treatment_prices tp2 ON s1.Treatments_ID = tp2.Treatments_ID
    AND s1.price = tp2.Price
INNER JOIN Hospital h2 ON tp2.Hospital_ID = h2.ID
INNER JOIN Treatments t2 ON tp2.Treatments_ID = t2.ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17eecc2/1/1)**:

```
|          TreatmentName | Hospital_Name | Price |
|------------------------|---------------|-------|
|           nose surgery |          pars |   700 |
|             Orthopedic |          Mehr |   300 |
| Knee joint replacement |         ghaem |   450 |
```

It's MUCH easier in later versions of MySQL or any other SQL language that allows window functions.

**MySQL 8+**:

```
SELECT s1.TreatmentName, s1.Hospital_Name, s1.Price
FROM (
    SELECT t.TreatmentName, h.Hospital_Name, tp.Price
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tp.Treatments_ID ORDER BY tp.Price) AS rn
    FROM treatment_prices tp 
    INNER JOIN Hospital h ON tp.Hospital_ID = h.ID
    INNER JOIN Cities c ON h.city_id = c.id
            AND c.ID = 2
    INNER JOIN Treatments t ON tp.Treatments_ID = t.ID
) s1
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b28f7543c3b127990654ad9e401c11a

Comment: Thank you So Much dear . you are the best

Answer (score 0):

You should use GROUP BY  hospitals.name_en  ,  treatments.title_en

```
SELECT Min(treatment_prices.dollar) AS price, 
       hospitals.name_en            AS hname, 
       treatments.title_en          AS title
FROM   treatment_prices 
       INNER JOIN hospitals 
               ON hospitals.id = treatment_prices.hospital_id 
       INNER JOIN treatments 
               ON treatments.id = treatment_prices.treatment_id 
WHERE  hospitals.city_id = 2 
GROUP  BY hospitals.name_en  ,  treatments.title_en
```

and for obtain the  hospital with min(price) should be

```
select  t.price, t.title, hospitals.name_en   

from (
  SELECT Min(treatment_prices.dollar) AS price, 
         treatments.title_en          AS title,
         treatment_prices.treatment_id 
  FROM   treatment_prices 
         INNER JOIN hospitals 
                 ON hospitals.id = treatment_prices.hospital_id 
         INNER JOIN treatments 
                 ON treatments.id = treatment_prices.treatment_id 
  WHERE  hospitals.city_id = 2 
  GROUP  BY  treatments.title_en, treatment_prices.treatment_id
) t 
INNER JOIN treatments ON treatments.id = treatment_prices.treatment_id  
    AND treatments.title_en   = t.title 
INNER JOIN hospitals  ON hospitals.id = treatment_prices.hospital_id   
    AND treatment_prices.dollar = t.price
```

Comment: Excuse me bro but phpmyadmin gave the nonsense error : 
#1146 - Table 'bloga.title' doesn't exist

Comment: Typo on `AND treatments.title_en   = t,title` ... it's a comma instead of a dot.

Comment: comma .. changed in dot

Answer (score 0):

It doest show the hospital it should because you there is only a `GROUP BY` the `treatment_id`, when you select a column with an aggregation function and dont include it in the group by the DBMS will spread the result for that column of the first row to all the rows it fetchs. So group first by `treatment_id` and then by `hospital_name` (or id) and that should do it. Leaving the query like this:

```
   SELECT Min(tp.dollar) AS price, 
          h.name_en      AS hname, 
          t.title_en     AS title 
    FROM   treatment_prices AS tp
           INNER JOIN hospitals AS h
                   ON h.id = tp.hospital_id 
           INNER JOIN treatments AS t 
                   ON t.id = tp.treatment_id 
    WHERE  h.city_id = 2 
    GROUP  BY tp.treatment_id, hname
```

Note that im using the alias for `h.name_en` in the `GROUP BY`, MySQL 8+ has no problem with this and it puts to use the aliases for more than for the visuals.

Also one last thing, and since I see other questions suggesting the use of subqueries, only use them if it's 100% a necessity and there's no other way. That's because subqueries create a query over a table that is not indexed and not normalized in the DB so if that table the subquery returns has too much data it will take a much longer time to complete the query than if it's done without the subquery. Maybe this doesnt have great effect while studying or learning but in the work enviroment time is crucial and the queries that give data to the many reports a department may do need to be fast and optimal.